# why bootstrap select picker not working on calling second time?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using bootstrap select picker. First time I initialize it with a select like

```
$("#abc").selectpicker();
```

and it works fine.

Now I am in edit mode. I want to show defaults (selected) values.
I am trying this.

```
$('#abc').val([2,14,18]);
$('#abc').selectpicker('refresh');
```

but it throws an error that

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function.

It is on the same page

Kindly help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you load both bootstrap and `jquery.js` ?
If you do, make sure bootstrap library has to be loaded last.

Comment: it is already done and first time its runs fine. But second time it gives this error

Comment: What exactly is "run first time and second time"? In a for loop or some thing else?
Uncaught TypeError seems that you don't get the correct library.
As I seem it may be some where you have load library again and cause this error.